# Timer in C# without System.Timers.timer

Tags: c#, timer

How do I create a timer in C# (Windows 8 phone development) where every second something gets added?

I have other methods going on in the background, so a delay will not work.  Also, my machine will not recognize System.Timers.Timer, so I need to use System.Windows.Threading, or some other method to get a timer implemented in my program.

Comment: System.Threading.Timer? http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.80).aspx. There's also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202942%28v=vs.105%29.aspx ( Background Agents )

Comment: Or [DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer(v=vs.105).aspx), if you want to do something on the UI thread?

Comment: Or async Tasks and sleep/delay?

Comment: Try making a variable which stores the immediate time upon instantiation. Then, compares the time it stored to the newest current time as you check for time elapsement